# accessing a siblings in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code :

```
<table><tr><td>hello</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="0" onkeypress="GetValue();" /></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="15"  /></td>
       </tr>
 </table>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function GetValue(){
      //  ???

       }
   </script>
```

how can i access the value of the third td ( the td with the value 15 ) 
without using the the easy way and give the td an id and call it i want by using .parent() or .siblings() this is a simple example to simplify my work but in my actual project the input have their value binded from DB and it's much more complicated any help apreciated

Comment: is the target td just after the td with the input? or is there a possibility something is in the way?

Comment: have a look at this jQuery function: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via the **:nth-child()** selector.

**JS code:**

```
$('table td:nth-child(3) input').val();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xzzUB/)

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the DOM element to `GetValue` function:

```
<input type="text" value="0" onkeypress="GetValue(this);" />
```

And use jQuery methods to get the value from the next text field:

```
function GetValue(that) {
    var val = $(that).parent().next().find("input").val();
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xzzUB/1/

Comment: Could you include a jsfiddle version, because I tried your solution via jsfiddle and it does net seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Change input like this:

`<input type="text" value="0" onkeypress="GetValue(this);" />`

and function to:

```
function GetValue(el){
  var sib = $(el).parent().siblings('td').last();
}
```

Comment: sib will be an array of all the siblings and not the last <td> element as requested by the op

Answer (score 0):

`$("td:eq(2) input").val()` will return 15

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<table id='theTable'><tr><td>hello</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="0" onkeypress="GetValue();" /></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="15"  /></td>
       </tr>
 </table>​​​
```

Use the nth-child() jQuery function

```
console.log($('#theTable td:nth-child(3)').children().val());​​​​​
```